# WCF client allows one operation to be run in parallel, but not another?

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf-client

I have a WCF SOAP client which I generated from a service WSDL.  The service offers, among other things, `query` and `batch` operations.  It also purports to offer multithreaded request handling.

In attempting to parallelize usages of my client, I am seeing an odd behavior: the client will happily send as many `query` requests as I tell it to in parallel, but it will only send one `batch` request at a time.  I'm using Fiddler to watch the traffic, and I can see 10 open `query` requests, but the `batch` requests always start and finish one at a time.

I'm using `Parallel.ForEach` for both code paths, with `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` set to 10.  I am not changing `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`, although I did notice that if I set it to fewer than the number of threads the `query` requests get throttled.  I have verified that the TPL is spinning up multiple threads by looking at the `ManagedThreadId` value in the parallelized execution paths.

As far as I can tell, the only difference from the client's point of view is that `query` uses the HTTP `GET` method, and `batch` uses the `POST` method.  Would this cause the behavior I'm seeing?  Is there something else I can look at?

**EDIT** As requested, here is the relevant client code (I've removed `ServiceKnownType` attributes)

```
//generated client interface
//{...
[OperationContract(Action = "", ReplyAction = "*")]
[FaultContract(typeof (fault), Action = "", Name = "fault")]
[XmlSerializerFormat(SupportFaults = true)]
[return: MessageParameter(Name = "return")]
QueryResponse query(QueryRequest queryRequest);

[OperationContract(Action = "", ReplyAction = "*")]
[FaultContract(typeof (fault), Action = "", Name = "fault")]
[XmlSerializerFormat(SupportFaults = true)]
[return: MessageParameter(Name = "return")]
BatchResponse batch(BatchRequest batchRequest);
//...}

//generated client class
//{...
public QueryResponse query(QueryRequest queryRequest)
{
  return this.Channel.query(queryRequest);
}

public BatchResponse batch(BatchRequest batchRequest)
{
  return this.Channel.batch(batchRequest);
}
//...}
```

**EDIT2**
Here is my debugging output, trying to track this down.

> `Creating...{Thread Id}` is written to the console immediately before I start putting together the payload for the `batch` operation
>
> `Sending...{Thread Id}` lines are written to the console immediately before the `batch` operation is invoked
>
> `Sent...{Thread Id}` lines are written to the console immediately after the `batch` operation completes

```
1:53:58 PM (Thread 4)
1:53:58 PM (Thread 19)
1:53:58 PM (Thread 20)
1:53:58 PM (Thread 16)
1:53:58 PM (Thread 18)
1:53:58 PM (Thread 17)
1:53:58 PM (Thread 7)
1:53:58 PM (Thread 15)
Creating...19
Creating...15
Creating...16
Creating...17
Creating...7
Creating...4
Creating...20
Creating...18
Sending...17
Sending...7
Sending...20
Sending...19
Sending...16
Sending...18
Sending...4
Sending...15
1:53:59 PM (Thread 22)
Creating...22
Sending...22
1:53:59 PM (Thread 23)
Creating...23
Sending...23
Sent...17
Sent...15
Sent...7
Sent...18
Sent...20
Sent...16
Sent...4
Sent...19
Sent...22
Sent...23
```

And here is the Fiddler log for this run:

[image]

For reference, here is a snip from the Fiddler log for the `query` code path:

[image]

Comment: Do you control the service? The service may be set to only process one call at a time. See chapter 8 in Juval's Programming WCF services book.

Comment: @EricScherrer No - the service is provided by a 3rd party.  Even if the service were throttling, I'd still expect to see connection requests waiting in Fiddler if the client was making multiple concurrent requests.

Comment: Can you post the client that got generated? Wondering if there are any interesting attributes on that method.

Comment: @EricScherrer I updated the question with that code.  There are no attributes on the class methods, but I included everything except the `ServiceKnownType` attributes on the interface methods.

Comment: I'm not so sure that there really is no difference in the way you treat the two methods. Try to create a minimal piece of code to reproduce this. Just call Parallel.ForEach with a made-up workload and a one-line body calling the service. Post the code here.

Comment: There certainly are differences in the way I treat the two methods, which I spent a good deal of time trying to eliminate as candidates for this behavior before posting the question.  I removed all of the code I could on the `batch` side while still sending a valid payload, and I added logging to verify that the code was actually behaving in a multithreaded manner.  I will append those logs, juxtaposed with a Fiddler screenshot.

Comment: @arootbeer ok I'm looking for very safe evidence that you are really calling into WCF on the client side in a concurrent manner. So far this is an assumption that I'm not comfortable making.

Comment: @usr I understand what you're looking for, and I agree with you that it's important to have.  I've updated the post with the information I felt I needed to convince myself that this really was happening in the WCF client.  Please feel free to ask for anything specific you'd like me to include.